# Vim/Gvim is no more indenting XML (when entering text) in the way I want

Tags: vim, gvim, xml, indentation

Given a file with extension `.xml`, I used to indent my content as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <p>This is a text
    containing <i>inline tags</i>
    like <i>here</i>
    and some other text.
  </p>
</root>
```

Up to  certain moment, the vim/gvim editor was indenting this content automatically: Each time the user pressed the enter key on the keyboard, the editor was adding or removing blank spaces at the beginning of the line in order to have the same indentation as shown above. This is the behaviour I want to get back.

But the current behaviour seems to be unaware of the presence of inline closing tags, so that the indentation look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <p>This is a text
    containing <i>inline tags</i>
      like <i>here</i>
        and some other text.
    </p>
  </root>
```

I tried a lot of receipts found on the Internet, but was not able to correct this behaviour, that is buggy in my eyes. I don't know where to start looking further.

Comment: Did you recently update Vim? Or any plugins?

Comment: No plugin, but possibly automatically updated. I do not edit XML every day, so this behaviour could have started some time ago.

Comment: What's your version of Vim?

Comment: Current installed version is 8.1.

Comment: Can you update to 8.2?

Comment: In Ubuntu, the latest version of vim/gvim is 8.1. Where can I find docs to upgrade to 8.2? I am ready to try snap or whatever if necessary.

Comment: You can try the instructions here: https://www.vim.org/git.php

Comment: @Heptite: Great, but will that install also gvim?

Comment: Yes, it should. The binary it creates should be both console and gVim in one.

Comment: Consider reporting an issue at https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/issues, that's where the indent plug-in for XML comes from. I reproduced this issue on Vim 8.2.2966, which seems to be recent enough to have all relevant changes from the upstream XML runtime support...

Comment: BTW, consider using the [vi.se] StackExchange for questions on Vim!